# Meteor accounts-facebook has no option to use https for redirect_uri

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, oauth

I am using meteor [accounts-facebook](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/accounts-facebook/facebook.js) and want to use it with SSL as required by Facebook, but the `redirect_uri` is passed as `http://`, even if the app is running on `https://`. The code which creates a `loginUrl` in [facebook-oauth.js](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/facebook-oauth/facebook_client.js) is as following:

```
var loginUrl =
        'https://www.facebook.com/v2.9/dialog/oauth?client_id=' + config.appId +
        '&redirect_uri=' + OAuth._redirectUri('facebook', config) +
        '&display=' + display + '&scope=' + scope +
        '&state=' + OAuth._stateParam(loginStyle, credentialToken, options && options.redirectUrl);
```

Which again calls in [OAuth](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/oauth/oauth_common.js):

```
OAuth._redirectUri = function (serviceName, config, params, absoluteUrlOptions) {
  ...
  Meteor.absoluteUrl('_oauth/' + serviceName, absoluteUrlOptions)
  ...
}
```

There in [Meteor.absoluteUrl](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/meteor/url_common.js) SSL is first removed before it is readded if `Meteor.absoluteUrl.defaultOptions.secure` is true:

```
  // merge options with defaults
  options = Object.assign({}, Meteor.absoluteUrl.defaultOptions, options || {});
  ...
  if (!/^http[s]?:\/\//i.test(url)) // url starts with 'http://' or 'https://'
    url = 'http://' + url; // we will later fix to https if options.secure is set
  ...
  // turn http to https if secure option is set, and we're not talking
  // to localhost.
  if (options.secure &&
      /^http:/.test(url) && // url starts with 'http:'
      !/http:\/\/localhost[:\/]/.test(url) && // doesn't match localhost
      !/http:\/\/127\.0\.0\.1[:\/]/.test(url)) // or 127.0.0.1
    url = url.replace(/^http:/, 'https:');
```

I don't see a way:

1. How to tell accounts-facebook to use the right protocol, because no `absoluteUrlOptions` parameter are passed to `OAuth._redirectUri`
2. How to set `Meteor.absoluteUrl.defaultOptions.secure`
3. Any other option...

My only **workaround** was to install `meteor add force-ssl` so the whole application is running forced on https.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A **workaround** is to install force-ssl so the whole application is running on https.

```
meteor add force-ssl
```

**Update:** apparently you can also just set `Meteor.absoluteUrl.defaultOptions.secure = true` at the right place early in your application, e.g. `client/lib/...`